# How to make files available not in "/static/", but in "/app/static/"?

Tags: django, django-static

I have Django 1.11 project structure like this:

- project
- - static
- - - img1.png
- - app
- - - static
- - - - img2.png

File "settings.py" contains:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Images are available at:

```
my-site.com/static/img1.png
my-site.com/static/img2.png
```

But I want the images to be available in a different way:

```
my-site.com/app/static/img1.png
my-site.com/app/static/img2.png
```

I can write to a file "project/app/urls.py":

```
urlpatterns += static('static/', document_root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app' + STATIC_URL))
```

And then "img2.png" will be available, but not "img1.png".
How can I make "img1.png" available?

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this...

```
urlpatterns += static('app/static/', document_root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL))
```

Comment: If I write in the file "project/app/urls.py":
urlpatterns += static('app/static/', document_root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL)) 

But the file "img1.png" is still not available. I can write: urlpatterns += static('static/', document_root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL))  And then the file "img1.png" will be available, but "img2.png" will not be available.

Comment: If the file "project/app/urls.py" contains: urlpatterns += static('static/', document_root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app' + STATIC_URL))
And the file "project/project/urls.py" contains: urlpatterns += static('app/static/', document_root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL))
Also, one image is available, and the second is not available.

Comment: Your static file url should be in project config folder not in any app (the folder where settings.py resides).